# How can I load a csv file which is too big in iPython?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bigdata, ipython

How can I load a csv file which is too big in iPython? It seems that it cannot be loaded at once in memory.

Comment: So the csv file is bigger than the RAM available?

Comment: @shuttle87 I dont know. It is an exercise and they suggested to try to download the data using a web browser. But I dont know how to do that ...

Comment: are you using pandas?  if so try the chunksize argument in the read_csv method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to read a file in chunks and it will also distribute the file over multiple processors.

```
import pandas as pd 
import multiprocessing as mp

LARGE_FILE = "yourfile.csv"
CHUNKSIZE = 100000 # processing 100,000 rows at a time

def process_frame(df):
        # process data frame
        return len(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        reader = pd.read_csv(LARGE_FILE, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
        pool = mp.Pool(4) # use 4 processes

        funclist = []
        for df in reader:
                # process each data frame
                f = pool.apply_async(process_frame,[df])
                funclist.append(f)

        result = 0
        for f in funclist:
                result += f.get(timeout=10) # timeout in 10 seconds
```